# wp admin populate select dropdown after checkbox change

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have custom post types called: **Categories**, **Messages** and **Tools**. I also have **custom taxonomy** called **Subcategories**.

Category has custom ACF post object field where you can select values from existing Tools, you also have to select Subcategory

Messages have custom taxonomy radio field where you have to select one of the Subcategories.

Messages can also have Tools, but only those that belong to the Category that has the same Subcategory as the message.

I'm using conditional logic to show Tools post object field when Subcategory is selected for the Message.
My problem is that I'm having hard time limiting Tools available in Message to only those that are from the Category with the same subcategory.

I've actually managed to get the list of Tools that can be displayed with change event listener on Subcategory radio and ajax, but I just dont know how to populate the Tool post object field.

```
$(window).on("load", function() {

    if (typeof(acf) == 'undefined') { 
        return; 
    }

    // radio taxonomy select
    var field = acf.getField('field_5dcd325ceb231');

    field.on('change', function(e) {
      // the field I would like to populate with the Tools I get in response
      var mandatory_tools = acf.getField('field_5dc1444f9dde7');
      // selected Subcategory Id
      var subcategory_id = field.val();
      if (!subcategory_id) {
        return;
      }

      $.ajax({
          url: ajaxurl,
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
              action: 'get_subcategory_tools',
              subcategory_id: subcategory_id,
          },
          success: function( response ) {
              response = JSON.parse( response );
              // console.log(response);
              if (response.success) {
                  // I get the array of object with tools that I want to be available for selection
                  let tools = response.tools;

                  // how to limit the selection to only those Tools that are in tools variable, 
                  instead of showing all tools
              }

          },
          error: function (xhr, status, error) {
              console.log( xhr.responseText );
          }
      });


    });  
});
```

Subcategory taxonomy radio field in Messages

[image: Subcategory taxonomy radio field in Messages]

Post object field for selecting Tools in Messages in which I only want to have Tools that are in response, instead of all of them

[image: Post object field for selecting Tools in Messages]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research it seems that it isnt possible to modify acf post object fields with ajax.

I got around this by creating acf select field and filling it with the stuff I need.

Select field can be updated by ajax